# Where does the second chord progression in the song imagination by Labrinth come from?

Tags: chord-theory, chord-progressions

In the song Imagination by Labrinth, there's a chord progression that I didn't understand. The first progression in the song is I iii ii V in the key of D major.
but then the second progression has chords D C Bm Gm which are not in the key of D. Can someone explain the second progression?

Answer (score 4):

So many folk seem to think 'if the chords/notes aren't in the key' there's somethng wrong. There's no rule saying they have to be diatonic. In fact, if that was the case, we'd have to lose the vast majority of songs and pieces we know and love.

There exists what's called the **parallel key**. That's the one with the same root note, but major *or* minor.

So, in the case of key D, there's more choice than I, ii, iii, IV, V, vi and Viio. That's D, Em, F♯m G, A Bm and C♯o.  There's all those belonging to key D *minor* to come out to play, too. That's Dm, Eo, F, Gm, Am, B♭, and C.

So, by mixing and matching the two sets of chords, we have all those in that song.

Comment: I understand, but then could chords from parallel keys resolve to the chords in the original key?

Comment: Yes, and they often do. There's also the Tierce de Picardie, all in minor, resolving to root major at the very end.

Comment: You don’t have to look very hard to find non-diatonic chords in music. The bVII In particular is so often used in rock/pop that there are articles about it and lists of dozens of famous tunes that contain it online. Here’s an interesting one: https://www.icce.rug.nl/~soundscapes/VOLUME22/Magnificent_flat-seventh.shtml

Comment: @exnihilo - that V7 chord exists in both major and its parallel minor - thanks to the harmonic and melodic versions of said minor.